# How can I plot a graph with a dataframe columns with datetime.datetime value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have different lists of y-values, example:

```
y1_values = [1, 4, 5, 3, 6]
y2_values = [3, 4, 2, 1, 2]
y3_values = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

and i have a pandas column, with the same lenght, with datetime.datetime values:

```
df['time'][0] =datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 19, 14, 30, tzinfo=tzutc())
df['time'][1] =datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 20, 14, 30, tzinfo=tzutc())
df['time'][2] =datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 21, 14, 30, tzinfo=tzutc())
df['time'][3] =datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 22, 14, 30, tzinfo=tzutc())
df['time'][4] =datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 23, 14, 30, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

how can i use those datetimes as values on x-axis and plot the different y values. Using matplotlib

Comment: did you have a look at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the DataFrame -

```
time_values = [
    datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 19, 14, 30), 
    datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 20, 14, 30),
    datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 21, 14, 30),
    datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 22, 14, 30),
    datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 23, 14, 30)]


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"y1": y1_values, "y2": y2_values,
     "y3":y3_values, "time": time_values})
```

You can do -

```
df.plot(kind='line', y=['y1', 'y2', 'y3'], x='time')
```

Comment: Thank you This did the trick! The only problem is that the list has actually thousands of datetimes with different hours/minutes. Do you know how I can add the tick values only at the beginning of each month with only the date, without hours/minutes?

Comment: You can control the `xticks` by adding the `df.plot(xticks=[...], kind='line', y=['y1', 'y2', 'y3'], x='time'))` and calculate this list by any logic you like.